# Foreground Service in clean code MVVM in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, service, foreground-service

My service is invoked through the broadcast receiver always when the phone state is changed. Then in the service call log is synced with remote API.
My service invokes use case for sync so my structure looks like this: `Screen -> ViewModel -> Service and Use Cases -> Repo -> Data.`

I am not experienced enough and I do not see a way to display call log on the screen and make it always up to date with call log changes. The call which I want to display on the screen comes from remote API.

I know that I can just create a set of classes to get the whole call log from API but I do not know how to implement ,,event" which can run this entire logic always when phone state changes. It is easy to do it straight forward but in the clean code that is the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your call log displayed in your app with real-time updates. If you want this data from an API, then you need to be using an API or backend that supports a real-time protocol (WebSocket, HTTP server-sent events, others). Without using a real-time protocol, you will have to constantly query your API on a regular interval to check for updates.

There are many options for this, but I think an easy option that integrates well with Android would be [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners). I believe they use WebSockets.